# checking all (visible) layers for crossorigin-parameter and return a variable depending on it

Tags: openlayers-3

i'm trying to receive a variable after i checked the layers of the map on their crossOrigin-Property (if given).

In fact I want to set my variable printposs=true/false.

As soon as **one visible layer** doesnt have the proper CrossOrigin-Value the variable should become possible=true and the function/foreach-loop can quit, returning the value "outside"

Thats what i got alreay with my poor JS-knowledge. But it seems the variable always keeps the value of the last processed layer.

JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wa5g90xb/3/ (I added browser console-logging)

```
map.getLayers().forEach(function (layer, idx, a) {
if (layer instanceof ol.layer.Group) {
    layer.getLayers().forEach(function (sublayer, jdx, b) {
        var origin = sublayer.getSource()['crossOrigin'];
        var visible = sublayer.getVisible();
        var title = sublayer.get('title');

        if (visible === true && origin == 'anonymous') {
        printposs=true;

        } else if (visible == false) {
            printposs = true;

        } else {
            printposs = false;

            //return printposs; can abort here as soon as one visible layer doesnt have Crossorigin
        }

        return printposs;
    });
    console.log('outer return:' + printposs + ' - It seems always the value of the last "processed" layer is returned')
}
```

});

Comment: For sure you have to set your variable to its initial value (`undefined`) at the beginning of the loop interaction.

Comment: directly after (function (layer, idx, a) { 
var printposs;
doenst seem to fix it.